# Characterization of cross product (proof that only exists in dimension 3)

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, bilinear-form

In order to show that the cross product exists only in $\mathbb R^3$, our teacher puts this remark, "Exercise left to the reader". I have no idea how to solve it. Here's the problem:

"Let $B:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a surjective bilinear map and antisymmetric so that $B(u,v)=0 \iff \text{u and v are linearly dependent}$. Then $n = 3$."

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What does exhaustive mean in this case? Surjective (I am guessing this is the meaning)? Or also bijective? And we should have $B:R^n \times R^n \to R^n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's wrong. There is also a [7D binary cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product) that satisfies the given properties.

There are exactly two cross products on a 3D inner product space, one for both possible orientations of space. But there are infinitely many 7D cross products - in fact, the space of all cross products on a 7D inner product space is topologically the same as  $\mathrm{SO}(7)/G_2\simeq S^7$.

In general, an $n$-dimensional $k$-ary cross product $X$ is defined to be an antisymmetric multilinear function of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which also satisfies a volume constraint: namely, $\|X(v_1,\cdots,v_k)\|$ ought to be the volume of the parallelepiped formed from $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ - which may be calculated using the Gramian determinant, $\mathrm{vol}^2=\det(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle)$.

The full classification of $k$-ary $n$-dimensional cross products is as follows:

- **Nullary** cross product exist in any dimension.
- **Unary** cross products exist in even dimensions.
- **Binary** cross products exist in dimensions $0,1,3,7$.
- **Ternary** cross products exist only in dimensions $4,8$.
- **Co-unary** cross products exist whenever $k=n-1$.
- **Over-ary** cross products exist whenever $k>n$.

Some commentary on these:

- The nullary and over-ary cross products are both identically $0$.
- The unary cross product is essentially multiplication-by-$i$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a $2n$-dimensional real inner product space (note that taking the real part of the sesquilinear complex inner product yields a real inner product).
- The binary cross products are given by the imaginary parts $\mathrm{Im}(ab)=a\times b$ in the real normed division algebras $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{O}$ respectively. Here, $\mathbb{H}$ is the quaternions and $\mathbb{O}$ is the octonions. The $0$D and $1$D binary cross products are both over-ary.
- The 7D binary and 8D ternary cross product both relate to the octonions (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852658/octonionic-formula-for-the-ternary-eight-dimensional-cross-product)).
- The co-unary cross product $X(v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1})$ is the unique vector perpendicular to the span of $\{v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1}\}$, oriented appropriately, of the correct magnitude. The nullary 1D, unary 2D, binary 3D, and ternary 4D cross products are all co-unary.

Comment: Good answer, just a small nitpick: nullary cross products are not identically zero, they are given by unit vectors (note that the determinant of the corresponding $0\times 0$ Gram matrix is $1$). As a consequence, they exist in any dimension other than $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $B_i=\sum_{jk}\varepsilon_{ijk}u_jv_k$. Hereafter, we'll [drop the $\sum$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). There are constraints on $\varepsilon_{ijk}$, e.g. antisymmetry ($\varepsilon_{ijk}=-\varepsilon_{jik}$) and orthogonality ($\varepsilon_{ijk}=-\varepsilon_{ikj}$). But beyond three dimensions, these leave some degrees of freedom, whereas in $3$ dimensions the symbol $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is determined up to scaling. The former fact is why the product @runway44 mentioned isn't unique, even up to scaling.